# Desktop software for data analysis, like Business Objects "Lite"

Tags: software-rec, charts, analysis

My data set is sourced from ~100k users, with a few million records scattered over a dozen tables. Just too big for Excel, but not quite a data warehouse. It's sourced from a web-sites user base and traffic data.

Excel would be nice, with it Pivot tables and charts, but it just chokes approaching 100k records. I am looking for a desktop application for data analysis, in the vein of Business Objects, only less ambitious.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at Microsoft PowerPivot.

It's a free add-in for Excel 2010 which is able to handle way more data than Excel can out of the box. The main purpose of the add-in is data analysis on a much larger scale than previously possible. With the help of new formula language (see the second link below to dive right into that stuff) and the possibility to connect multiple tables into one pivot table it's possibilities are really much broader than the standard Excel table used to offer.

Download over here: https://www.microsoft.com/bi/en-us/solutions/pages/powerpivot.aspx

A great resource to get started is this: http://www.powerpivotpro.com/
(check out the sections "New Visitor?" and "What is PowerPivot?")

Comment: This is Windows only, but sounds very useful. I'll ask a colleague to try it out. Thanks!

Comment: True but definitely worth trying and I'd argue also worth setting up a virtual machine dedicated for this. Let me know what you think about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try xlreport.com. It allows you to real time connect to your database and automatically create a pivot table and chart.